# Python + boost: Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea

Tags: python, boost, c++

Вот пытаюсь прикрутить к свей проге (С++) питоновый интерпретатор с блекджеком и доступными девушками, но буст упорно не собирается пишет

> `..\boost_1_51_0\boost\config\auto_link.hpp|354|fatal error C1189: #error :  "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea...`

Как быть?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527713/mixing-a-dll-boost-library-with-a-static-runtime-is-a-really-bad-idea

Comment: Я это гуглил - тут ничего неясно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На windows XP сталкивался с такой же проблемой, когда пытался собирать из под VisualStudio 2008   решение таится имено в этом сообщении:

> Changing to Dynamic Runtime Linking (/MD and /MDd) is not feasible since static linking was chosen (1) due to security considerations, and (2) another library uses static linking.

суть проблемы кроется в multithreaded build сейчас уже точно не вспомню всех подробностей, но толи буст не дружит с /MD (надо /MT) толи наоборот подавай ему /MD и соответственно при заупске рядом с проектом (или в libs) должны лежать python.dll и boost****.dll   [/MD, /MT, /LD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)   возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120169/msvc-boostpython-static-linking-to-dll-pyd) или [в google](https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=boost+python+fatal+error+C1189&oq=boost+python+fatal+error+C1189&gs_l=hp.3...214009.220794.1.221479.16.15.1.0.0.0.297.2295.1j12j2.15.0...0.0...1c.1j2.rWiYhuMJsH8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=f2366ed39e950cfe&biw=1600&bih=768) вам помогут.. мне однажды помогло)

Comment: Да, спасиба с /md все собралось.

Comment: благодарности выражаются принятием правильного ответа;)